# Is there a way to make Hubot reply to all messages that are not existing commands?

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

I'm giving Hubot a first try, and I'm making a dialog script for basic conversation. I have completed quite a few possibilities (I have a lot of questions and keywords working,) but when the user asks or says something Hubot doesn't recognize, it's complete silence.

**I want to add a default set of answers for Hubot when it can't find an existing command or words** (vague replies like "*That's interesting*" or "*Tell me more*".)

Is there a way to do this via script? Something like:

```
robot.respond / * /, (msg) ->
    msg.send ArrayOfVagueReplies
```

where * is "everything else". "If *commands*... else..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since hubot's `robot.respond` method takes a regex, you should be able to just supply `/.*/` as the regex, and have it match everything.

So you'd have:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
        robot.respond /.*/i, (msg) ->
            doSomething(msg)
```

Comment: Awesome. Do you by any chance know where I can find a list of expressions I can use for creating more complicated matchings? For example, I'm using "()" and "|" but I don't know if there are more or how to exactly locate them: /(w|W)ho are you|(w|W)hat('s| is) your name/

Comment: There are many good regex tutorials online. Try searching Google for 'coffeescript regex' for specific code examples, but any regex should work between the the two forward slashes `/   /`

Comment: BTW, check out https://regex101.com/ It's not the best tutorial, but excellent for testing out and explaining how your regexs work.

Answer (score 4):

use `robot.catchAll` clause to catch all non-matched dialogues, you can reference to https://www.npmjs.com/package/hubot-suggest