# Hubot help desk: reply with error if x is not there

Tags: coffeescript, slack, hubot

I am giving hubot a go to be integrated with slack to act as a helpdesk.

The script (coffeescript) so far looks out for keywords, if the keywords don't exist then I need the hubot to return something like 'Sorry I can't find what you are looking for'.

Below is an example of the keyword query;

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /ansible/i, (res) ->
     res.send "Hi, for all ansible related querys, please go to 
     www.github.com/ansible/ansiblehelp"
```

So for example is ansible is not in the question, the hubot needs to reply with 'Sorry I can't find what you are looking for'.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try a `catchAll` clause to provide a default response:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.catchAll (msg) ->
    if msg.message.match /// ^#{robot.name}\s ///
        msg.reply "Sorry I can't find what you are looking for"
```

[Answer source](https://gist.github.com/sakatam/10f9a98f45fb5ff52e33)

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960159/is-there-a-way-to-make-hubot-reply-to-all-messages-that-are-not-existing-command)

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but it is throwing the below error; error: unexpected if
    if msg.message.match /// ^#{myhubot}\s ///

Comment: Take a look at this example as well: https://github.com/hassaku/hubot-suggest/blob/636f59b8d81407e3dae0048ade326bb6e02980c3/scripts/suggest.coffee#L64-L70